# Merging several dataframes or csv's on R - the ultimate method?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, merge

I have read.csv'ed about 20 files into data frames and I want to set up a pipeline to merge these and others in the future into one big data frame. I know of this particular function written for when more than two csv's need merging:

```
multmerge = function(mypath){
filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)})
Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y,all = TRUE)}, datalist)
}

MergedData=multmerge("file path")
```

However, it does not work with me (have pasted the error message below) and I think a possible reason is that my data frames have more than one shared variable (variables called the same way). Unfortunately the code above does not allow me to specify the variable by which to merge. Is there a way to either improve the function or maybe a completely different method to do this?

The error:

```
Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<a7>Y<95>s<6e><e9><87>A<f9>'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
5: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
 
 Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<a7>Y<95>s<6e><e9><87>A<f9>'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the `by` option in `merge`

Comment: merge only allows to merge two files and I want to do a batch (at least 20) in a way that I don't have to do them one by one.

Comment: Yes, I meant in the `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('col1', 'col2')...`. Here, in the code, you are not specifying the `by` option.  So, it could take all the column names that are common as `by`

Comment: Thank you! Do I put the names of the dataframes in the place of the dots ( . . . ) ?

Comment: I meant `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('col1', 'col2')), datalist)`. Here 'col1', 'col2' are just imaginary names.   I don't know your column names.  So, please change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In the `merge`, we can specify the column names to `merge`

```
 multmerge <- function(mypath){
  filenames <- list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist <-  lapply(filenames, read.csv, header=TRUE)
  Reduce(function(...) merge(...,all = TRUE, by = c('col1', 'col2')), datalist)
 }

 MergedData=multmerge("file path")
```

Comment: @MonikaGrigorova okay, not clear about your comment

Comment: Sorry, I posted my last comment before I could finish it: I tried the suggestion above and I get the same error message. In specifying the function do I leave 'col1' if I want it to merge by my first column? Or do I need to specify the variable in some way in calling the function later on?                        multmerge <- function(mypath){
  filenames <- list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist <-  lapply(filenames, read.csv, header=TRUE)
  Reduce(function(...) merge(...,all = TRUE, by = c('col1')), datalist)
}

MergedData=multmerge( 'path')

Comment: @MonikaGrigorova Use the column name of your datasets instead of 'col1'.  it is just a placeholder